# Why is "Enable Address Sanitizer" disabled in Xcode 7?

Tags: clang, xcode7, address-sanitizer

I read about the Runtime Sanitization in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) in the new Xcode 7, so I looked for it, and found that it's disabled. I'm using Xcode 7 GM seed.

When I go into the Run action of the scheme > Diagnostics tab, the `Enable Address Sanitizer` option is disabled:

[image]

There is some explanation about how other options are disbled, but no mention of why the sanitization option would be disabled:

> Some diagnostic tools can be used in combination with others; the options available on the Diagnostics pane are enabled and disabled as different options are chosen to help you select option combinations. For example, enable the address sanitizer and other, incompatible tools are disabled and cannot be chosen

Looking at the [Clang 3.8 documentation for Addresssanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), it looks like it can also be enabled, by adding a flag: `-fsanitize=address`. But where this flag should be used in the build settings is a mystery, and questionable since it also exists as a checkbox option in the scheme.

Also found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380264/1231948), but it is rather complex, and probably outdated, since it was back in 2013.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't currently use Guard Malloc and Address Sanitizer together. Selecting the Enable Guard Malloc checkbox disables the Enable Address Sanitizer checkbox. Deselect the Enable Guard Malloc checkbox if you want to use Address Sanitizer.

Comment: I already had `Enable Guard Malloc` selected, and didn't think of deselecting it. Thanks!

Comment: Enabling one of the following options prevents using Address Sanitizer : Enable Malloc Scribble, Enable Malloc Guard Edges, Enable Guard Malloc and Malloc Stack. All of these options should be unchecked so that the Address Sanitizer can be activated.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to be sure you have a Mac/iOS/TV simulator selected, not a device.  Watch simulator is not supported. (As of Xcode 9)