# iTunes Connect "Address Sanitizer Detected" email after uploading

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am having issues uploading my app to iTunes Connect for Testflight testing. I don't receive any errors when uploading the build through Xcode 7.0, but after my build attempts to processes on iTunes Connect I get the following automated email from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MY_APP". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> **Address Sanitizer Detected** - The executable ${executablePath} links in the Address Sanitizer. Please remove Address Sanitizer usage before submitting to the App Store.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I've ensured that "Enable Address Sanitizer" is unchecked for all of my build schemes. I cleaned the build folder and attempted to upload a clean build, but am still having the same issue. I don't see anything in the build settings related to Address Sanitizer.

Is there something else I need to do to remove Address Sanitizer?

Comment: Same here around the same timeframe as you. Our apps were stuck in processing before. Curious, do you use any crash reporting tools?

Comment: Were you able to upload builds previously? And yeah, I have Fabric/Crashlytics linked.

Comment: Welp, looks like I'm going to try to upload with Crashlytics removed :)

Comment: And we haven't been able to upload and TestFlight since Xcode 7 (meaning, our window opened barely a week ago).

Comment: Good thinking—maybe their frameworks were built with the sanitizer flag with their latest update. Are using Fabric 1.3.9? My app is in the store, but this is also the first upload I've tried with Xcode 7 (and I just updated Fabric). Well, I'm glad I'm not the only one...

Comment: We have a fairly stale Fabric (pre-Answers). Going to try without it first, then I'll try updating to latest if that passes through to TestFlight.

Comment: Don't use any crash reporting tools but still same situation. Don't even find the Address Sanitizer setting.

Comment: @Matt I tried removing all crash reporting tools and 3rd party frameworks but am still having the issue—so I don't think it's that. And the only Address Sanitizer setting that I know of is in the scheme settings under Run -> Diagnostics.

Comment: Running into the same issue

Comment: I removed HockeyApp and the build came through. However, the layout of iTunes Connect just updated, which makes me believe the server might just have bugged out. Wondering if I should create another build with HockeyApp included to see what happens now.

Comment: I removed Hockey App too, however, still got this very same error. Not sure what exactly this means. Could not find anything of this sort in Build Settings or Scheme settings as well.

Comment: [Possible Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632496/why-is-enable-address-sanitizer-disabled-in-xcode-7)  This shows that we need to uncheck all the checkboxes over here (thats what I did)

Comment: Same problem though! Anyone solved this anytime?

Answer (score 5):

we hit this same problem and our team spent the last 48 hours trying to isolate it.  Turns out that it was a naming conflict in one of the bundles that we were including.  Since the bundle is part of our standard SDK stack that we include in every game submission and we never had any issues with it before, I am assuming that something was upgraded on Apple's back-end to include checks for a lots of the new xCode features which caused the naming conflict during the post submission auto-code checks.

it took us over 20 submissions to isolate the offending bundles and renaming them fixed the problem.  If you're hitting this issue, I suggest going through your plist to see if any of the bundle names have used keywords that are  reserved for Address Sanitizer usage.  It was one of our engineers that identified the problem and he's away on vacation for the next week but apparently, he replaced the hyphens in the bundle name with underscores and the problem disappeared.

Wanted to share this one quickly and hope it helps folks that are stuck on this issue as it was an absolute nightmare for us to pin down.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Henry. Any ideas on what the keyword was or what some reserved Address Sanitizer keywords are? I'd like to accept this answer if we can get a concrete idea of how to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Hi Jay, we believe that the "hyphens" were causing the problem.  replacing the hyphens with underscores actually did the trick for us.

Comment: I can confirm this. I removed all the hyphens from bundle names of extensions (today, watchkit) and I no longer get the e-mail. Thanks!

Comment: awesome, glad this worked for you as well.  This is perhaps the most obscure and misleading error message we've ever encountered with iTunesConnect. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to some help from @Erik-Kerber, I managed to get a build through.

I was running the GM of Xcode 7 (7A218). After updating to the release build (7A220) from the App Store my app successfully passed iTunes Connect processing.

Comment: Could also have been iTunes Connect bugging out. They just updated the site and that process might also have messed up something in their validation systems as well.

Comment: I've tried one build with Xcode 7A220 but same issue.

Comment: Same here. Build on Itunes connect is still processing: `2.3.3 (71) (Processing) September 25, 2015 11:59 AM`

Answer (score 2):

My build also get rejected. 
I am using Fabric / Crashlytic library in my project.
I was also having the same issue and the same mail i got from Apple when my build rejected by Apple.

**But after replacing my Fabric/Crashlytics library with updated library it get solved and accepted by Apple Succefully.**